# What is the best way to automate preprending a proxy link to the current chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I regularly visit journal articles where I need to prepend my proxy link in order to get full access. I would ideally like a bookmark that takes the current site `url` `https://www.example.com` and prepends the `proxy link` `https:www.example2.com/login?url=` so that the current tab navigates to `https:www.example2.com/login?url=https://www.example.com`.

Is there a way to set a chrome bookmark relative to the current site? Or perhaps I need to make a quick extension myself.

Comment: Should be possible using some existing extension for URL redirection. Prefer those that use declarativeNetRequest as it's being applied by the browser internally, which is more efficient, so this is what you should use in your extension as well. See also [this example](/a/73392754).